# What is the single most influential book every designer should read?

Tags: resource-recommendations

What is the single most influential book every designer should read?

Comment: influential is a sort of specific condition, but at the same time a bit vague.. influencing what? If I made a question on what was the most 'useful' graphic design book instead, it would be called a duplicate, right? But nonetheless something like Graphic Design Referenced is very useful, but it's pretty young so it can't exactly be called influential...

Answer (score 41):

From the standpoint of a designer that must display technical information, there is no better bible than the series of books by [Edward Tufte](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/index):

- The Visual Display of Quantitative
  Information
- Envisioning Information
- Visual Explanations: Images and
  Quantities, Evidence and Narrative
- Beautiful Evidence

I re-read these books (or page through them) every time I'm stuck with a tricky design problem.

Comment: what do you suggest should I start between those books? (in which order?)

Comment: I started with 'The Visual Display of Quantitative Information'.  Out of the first 3 titles, it has always been the most useful for me when I need to display technical data.

Comment: They're good, but in my experience a bit narrow in focus. I find that all the actual, practical design principles from these are, in my experience, better articulated, better scoped, better organised and better linked to evidence in the excellent **Universal Principles Of Design** (below). Of the four, def start with "Visual Display...". As showcase books, however, they are very good.

Answer (score 30):

[The Elements of Typographic Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881792063) by Robert Bringhurst is generally considered the definitive guide to typography.

Comment: Written by a poet, this is a well-written book about typography.

Answer (score 22):

[Don't Make Me Think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0789723107), by Steven Krug.

Comment: @e100 - True, but the premise of the book, 'Don't make me think', could be applied to many areas of graphic design.

Comment: Fair enough, but it makes me think you are a programmer ;-)

Comment: @e100 Which he is. I bet a large percentage of us here are.

Comment: Second that notion - while Steve Krug's book is primarily for web designers, the whole premise holds true for a graphic designer of any sort. Graphic Designers have the job of communicating a message through art/design, so thinking about how the user will interact with ANY piece of communication is a critical task for any designer.

Comment: @e100 As a web/user interface designer, it's difficult / unwise not to be somewhat of a programmer as well these days.

Answer (score 22):

[The Design of Everyday Things](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465067107) by Donald Norman.

Answer (score 15):

[Universal Principles of Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592535879)

Comment: This book really is brilliant and underrated: evidence-based, brilliantly presented, just the right level of detail to be usable as a reference when facing a difficult problem. Also it's not too specific: ultimately good design practice is rooted in human behaviour and cognition, and this shows very well how the same principles work and can be applied across many fields.

Comment: absolutely! I loved it at first sight, and learned a lot of useful things.

Comment: YES, The first time I saw this book, I bought a case of them (12 or so) and gave them away to friends and colleagues. It started a bunch of spin-offs.

Answer (score 10):

[Megg's History of Graphic Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471699020): This is a textbook, but it's a great resource if you can get your hands on it.  It's a fairly comprehensive rundown of the major events of Graphic Design history, which is something any aspiring designer should be familiar with.

Also, I would check out the [recommended reading section](http://jasonsantamaria.com/reading/) on Jason Santa Maria's blog--any of those titles would be well worth checking out (I'm still working through them myself.)

Answer (score 9):

I'd certainly recommend [Problem Solved: A Primer in Design and Communication by Michael Johnson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0714844535). It's a good introduction, with real case studies of client briefs. The problem - solution format is likely to be quite appealing to users of this and other SE sites, too.

The [johnson banks website](http://www.johnsonbanks.co.uk/) and especially [blog](http://www.johnsonbanks.co.uk/thoughtfortheweek/index.php) might give you a bit of a taster.

Answer (score 7):

[Robin Williams - The Non-Designer's Design Book](http://www.peachpit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321534042), PeachPit Press. Very good.

Comment: There is now "The Non-Designer's Design and Type Books", which contains both.

Answer (score 6):

On the psychological side, i'd like too add :

Colin Ware : Visual Thinking for design

Stephen Kosslyn : Graph design for the eye and the mind.

Answer (score 5):

['Visual Grammar'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568985819) by Christian Leborg

and

[Design Elements: A Graphic Style Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592532616)
by Timothy Samara

and

[How Designers Think, Fourth Edition: The Design Process Demystified][3]
by Bryan Lawson

The above are must-reads...I will post longer, category-wise list later.

Answer (score 4):

The Power of the Center: A Study of Composition in the Visual Arts, 20th Anniversary Edition by, Rudolf Arnheim and Interaction of Color by, Josef Albers.

Answer (score 3):

I'll promote it till i am blue in the face. [Logo Design Love](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321660765) is a great book. Everyone should own it. Given it is pretty limited to logo design but ideas from it can be useful for any graphic design job.

Answer (score 2):

I have to go with a classic in this case:

[image]

Müller-Brockmann, Josef: [Grid Systems in Graphic Design.](http://forsale.objectsinspaceandtime.com/detail/grid-systems-in-graphic-design)

It predates the web -- but everything is still pretty applicable.

Many contemporary [remixes](http://forsale.objectsinspaceandtime.com/detail/the-designer-and-the-grid) and [revisitations](http://forsale.objectsinspaceandtime.com/detail/making-and-breaking-the-grid-a-graphic-design-layout-workshop-graphic-design) are available to adapt Mr. Müller-Brockmann's practical opus of pragmatic design to the internet era, should the reader want or need such a thing.

Srsly kids, get one today. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 1):

E. F. Schumacher, A Guide For The Perplexed.

It has nothing to do with your work, and yet, it will affect everything that you do.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the books that Jason Santa Maria has on his **[recommended reading list](http://v4.jasonsantamaria.com/reading/)** for designers, such as:

- *Making and Breaking the Grid* by Timothy Samara
- *Graphics Artists Guild Handbook: Pricing & Ethical Guidelines* by Graphic Artists Guild
- And of course as mentioned above, *The Elements of Typographic Style*
  by Robert Bringhurst

Answer (score 0):

[How Buildings Learn](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140139966) is literally about architecture, but conceptually fits into a lot of concepts--especially in the context of web design and software design in general. It's one I've recommended for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

- [Robert Bringhurst: The Elements of Typographic Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881791326) (already listed, but not to be missed)
- [Jost Hochuli: Detail In Typography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2917855665) (to complement the first one)
- [Adrian Shaughnessy: How to Be a Graphic Designer without Losing Your Soul](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568989830)