# What is a good book/guide on Graphic Design for a complete beginner?

Tags: tutorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips and sources for programmers who must or want to learn graphic design.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-sources-for-programmers-who-must-or-want-to-learn-graphic-design)

I am a programmer, though I am quite interested in visual design, interaction design and usability.

What is a good source, perhaps a book or online guide on the subject of Graphic Design for the web?

It would preferably be based on some solid theory, not just collection of how-tos and tips and tricks.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-sources-for-programmers-who-must-or-want-to-learn-graphic-design

Comment: I vote for close, duplicate as well for books resources over here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-designer-should-read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Power of the Center: A Study of Composition in the Visual Arts, 20th Anniversary Edition by, Rudolf Arnheim and Interaction of Color by, Josef Albers.