# How do I find examples of single 2-D non-animated info-graphics with 4 or 5 dimensions within a single graph?

Tags: resource-recommendations, information-graphics, information-design

Really not sure how to explain what I'm looking for, just know it exist.

For example, dimensions might include time, volatility, space, distance, density, etc. -- basically any measurement that's able to be tied to another measurement.

So, basically I'm looking for a info-graph that measures 4 or 5 different measurements that tie together within one graph -- but the question is how did you go about finding examples, not a request for an example.

Comment: "how did you go about finding examples"? Not sure this question really has an answer, other than "do the research".

Comment: @e100: Not really, since to do a search you need to know keywords, and I do not know of a search that will result even one valid result in the first ten search results.

Comment: Did you try "4 [or multi] dimensional graph"? Also, Edward Tufte's books are *the* primer for this sort of problem: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/159/70

Comment: In response to your comment on @plainclothes' answer: the Wikipedia definitions of "dimension" and "graph" are rather specialised. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plot_%28graphics%29 may be useful - but they cover much of the same ground. I think one of the problems is that all these words have slightly different accepted meanings depending on what field you're in.

Comment: Thanks. I've read Tufte's books and attend a day workshop with him. And yes, I've used Google Images to Google multi dimensional graph not seeing anything other than serialized multi dimensional graphs; meaning a number of dimensions are aligned to a single dimension such as time, scale, etc. -- I'm looking for something more complex than just simple one-to-many graphs. As for "dimension" and "graph" being context dependent, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by digging around here: http://infosthetics.com/

And here: http://www.visualcomplexity.com/vc/

Comment: Thank you. How did you find those suggestions? ()

Comment: I'm obsessive about research ;) These sites have been around a while. When you stay tapped into the design community, things just fall into your lap.

Comment: To be honest, still think it is possible I missing understanding what a [dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_%28data_warehouse%29) is... any suggestions for defining what exactly it means?